# Server endpoint calling address and redirecting address returning different ip address

Tags: java, spring-boot, redirect, networking, server

I have two servers with different domain.

Server 2: Ip address is `200.200.200.200` (twohundred.com)

Server 1: Ip address is `100.100.100.100` (onehundred.com)

I am making a rest API request from server2 to server1. In server1 I have a java endpoint called **/validate**. From this endpoint, I make a request to **/verify** endpoint hosted in the same server.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public String validateAndRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response) throws JSONException, IOException {
    Url url = "https://onehundred.com/verify?queryParam=123";
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    response.sendRedirect("https://onehundred.com/successful/message");
}
```

If a request is sent from the browser to /verify endpoint and from their, if I redirect to /validate, Is it possible to redirect from server address.

Comment: Are you trying ask that you want know the requester IP address while serving the request?

Comment: @Sunil Kanzar, I am asking , when i do sendRedirect then the request goes to /successful endpoint. In successful endpoint the request came from ip address (200.200..*) which is server2 even though the code where response.sendRedirect lives is hosted in server 1(100.100.100.100).

So, /successful endpoint should receive request from server1 and not from server2.

Comment: I don't get you question, if requesting on `https://onehundred.com/successful/message` which is hosted on `server 1` and expect it to call by `server 1` it self.

Comment: I mean to say if you are making call from `server 1` to the `server 1` it self then how can you expect it to came from `server 2`?

Comment: THat is what i am saying, In successful endpoint the request coming is from server 2 even though the  sendredirect code is physically stored in server1 and running in server1.

So, /successful endpoint should receive request from server1 but looking at the logs, request is actually coming from /server2 (200.200.200.200)

Comment: I just want to change the address, such that /successful endpoint should receive request from server1 and not from server2. That is response.sendRedirect should send server1 ip address and not server2.

Comment: Okay, So from which request header you are taking that sender IP address to print it in logs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194587/discussion-between-sunil-kanzar-and-lambad).

Comment: Hay, bro this channel is public and if your mansion IP address is public one then please remove it.

Answer (score 1):

It happen because `sendRedirect` will send redirection code to the client and client will make another http call to the server.

So if you want actual server IP than you have to make HTTP call from `server 1` it self.

To Solve this problem just do the same thing for `https://onehundred.com/successful` which you have done for `https://onehundred.com/verify?queryParam=123` API and parse the response of success API and display it in the current API(`/validate`).

Here in this case request made by `server 1` it will not send redirection request to the client.

Sorry for English